# Gaussian random variable as measurable function.

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

I am in a bit of a muddle trying to reconcile my measure theoretic knowledge with the hand wavey way of dealing with random variable I first encountered.

So when I first saw a one dimensional Gaussian random variable, call it $X$, I was just given the definition
$$P(X \in B) = \int_B \phi(x) dx$$
where $\phi(x)$ is the appropriate exponential function for whatever our mean and variance is.

Now a random variable should be a measurable function and when we write
$$P(X \in B)$$
we actually want the measure of the pre-image of $B$ under $X$.

If $P \colon \mathcal{A} \to [0,1]$ sends $A \mapsto \int_A \phi(x)dx$ and $X\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}; x \mapsto x$ then our two ways of thinking about a Gaussian give us the same answer but this seems wrong as then a Gaussian random variable is more a measure than a measurable function (every one would be the identity).

What is our measure and what is $X$ as a function?

Comment: The measure is exactly as you say, and the function is exactly as you say; $X$ is the function from $\Bbb R$ to itself defined by $X(t)=t$. I don't understand why you say this makes $X$ "more a measure than a function". Of course there are other ways to define $P$ and $X$, but this is perfectly valid. It's _true_ that if you have _any_ random variable $X$ and you're given $P(X\in E)$ then one way to define $P$ and $X$ is to do exactly this.

Comment: So then how can we derive what $P(X+Y \in B) = P(id + id \in B)$ without just assuming it is what it 'should be'. I ask because I got confused trying to show the sum of two Gaussians is Gaussian.

Comment: Your post talked about _one_ random variable. My comment was about _one_ random variable. If you have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ then no, you cannot realize them both as the identity function. (Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ you can realize them both as functions from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$, with $X(s,t)=s$ and $Y(s,t)=t$. The relevant measure on $\Bbb R^2$ is then the joint distribution $\mu(E)=P((X,Y)\in E)$.)

Answer (score 4):

A *real-valued* random variable is an $\mathcal F$-measurable function $X:\Omega\to\Bbb R$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\Bbb P)$ is a probability space. The *distribution* (or *law*) of $X$ is the image measure $\Bbb P_X$ defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ of $\Bbb R$ by $\Bbb P_X(B):=\Bbb P[X^{-1}(B)]=\Bbb P[\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in B]$, $B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.
In this context the name "Gaussian" is attached to $X$ if the distribution measure $\Bbb P_X$ is has a normal density:
$$
\Bbb P_X(B)=\int_B {1\over\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2)\,dx,\qquad B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R),
$$
for appropriate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.